# A question on non noetherian ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a reduced commutative non noetherian ring of dimension $d$  and $a$ a non zero divisor. Can I say that Krull dimension of $R/(a)$ is at most $d - 1$?

Comment: Just now I realized that in any arbitrary reduced commutative ring set of zero divisors is the union of minimal primes. So I got the answer of the first part of my question.

Answer (score 5):

Since $a$ is a non-zerodivisor of $R$, it does not lie in any of the minimal primes of $R$.  Therefore any chain of primes in $R$ that all contain $(a)$ has no minimal prime in the chain and can therefore be extended to a larger chain of primes in $R$, namely, by including a prime properly contained in the smallest prime in the chain.  So $\dim R/(a) < \dim R$.

Comment: One might note that this does not need the ring $R$ to be reduced (as in the question).

Comment: And it also holds for Noetherian rings.  Place *haha* emoticon here.